# ScrollView does not resize directly after child changes

Tags: android, resize, scrollview

I've run into a very annoying problem regarding ScrollView resizing, and I'm running out of possible solutions.

I have a FragmentPager containing several different Fragments, one of which has a ScrollView.
The Fragment with the ScrollView is made up of a Spinner and the ScrollView containing a LinearLayout with several rows of other Views (such as SeekBars, Buttons, Edittexts) in it.
Depending on which option is select in the Spinner, the ScrollView shows different views. To do so, some Views have their visibility turned to Gone, while others are turned to Visible. 
This works great, except for the fact that the ScrollView does not seem to resize itself properly upon choosing a different option using the Spinner.

When the ScrollView is full of Views, and therefore scrollable, if the user selects an option which shows less Viewsthan required to fill the ViewPort the ScrollView still scrolls.
When the user then chooses the old option again, the ScrollView is now unable to scroll since it took on the size required for the previous option. 
When the user then chooses the SAME option again, the ScrollView suddenly is scrollable, since it is now resized to the actual size required.

What is going on here? And better yet, how can I fix this annoying problem?

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control_scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#DD000000"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lamp_choose_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/choose_lamp_text"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lamp_select_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#DD000000"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lamp_settings_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="#44000000"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="@string/lamp_settings_text"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Lamp name -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/naam_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bridge_naam"
                style="@style/ConfigText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/config_lightname"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/lamp_naam_input"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/tasstextfield"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible" />
<!-- Rest of the views -->
```

Things I already tried:

- ForceLayout/requestLayout on the parent ScrollView
- Invalidate the ScrollView
- ForceLayout/requestLayout on the containing LinearLayout
- Invalidating the LinearLayout
- Invalidating all children of the ScrollView
- ForceLayout/requestLayout  on all children of the ScrollView

Comment: Have you tried using a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) instead of building what appears to be your own list view? Ignore the `Loader` example on that page -- you can simply create a `String[]` or `List<String>` with each piece of text and feed that to an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), then override `getView` to control the appearance.

Comment: I can see why you would think that. In reality I stopped using TextViews as that was basically just for testing purposes, and am now using different Views such as Buttons, EditTexts and Seekbars. The problem however, still remains.

Comment: I believe the issue is the `ScrollView` needs to resize itself for the new `Views`.  When you set the inner views are set to `View.VISIBLE` call `requestLayout()` or `forceLayout()` on the parent ScrollView to schedule a layout pass.

Comment: Updated my question with the things I already tried, seems like they didn't stick the first time. Sadly, I already tried invalidating, requestLayout and forceLayout on all of the Views. The problem still remains.

Comment: Hmm... Other option you can try, don't use `View.GONE` and instead add/remove them as needed.  It might be what eventually forces the resizing. There's added overhead, but not much more than what you're trying to do already.  Just hold on to the references of the `Views`, and you won't have to re-inflate them. Just drop them in.

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer FWIW, a `ListView` can display _any_ kind of views (including complex layouts, nested views, etc.). It is not limited to simple TextViews, and the views in the list don't need to be the same. It might still fit the bill.

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer Can you try to remove the `fillViewport` attribute and at the same time set the height to "wrap_content"?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Just tried that, it only resulted in my ViewPort showing just half of my Views, cutting off the rest.

Comment: @Sandervan'tVeer ok. I'd like you to use a Handler to post the ForceLayout/RequestLayout/Invalidation. In other words, do not use setVisibility followed directly by whatever you tried. For example, use `new Handler().post(new Runnable() {public void run() {invalidateMyViews}});` If this doesnt make a difference, use `postDelayed` instead of `post`. I hope you know what I am talking about, and please let me know what happens to the ScrollView's behavior now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be the most enjoyable solution, but it might work.
Use a handler to post a delayed message to refresh the view a second time, as if the user would choose the same option twice after having click on the refresh button.

```
// The code when the user wants to update the views 
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    updateView();
    Message m = Message.obtain();
    m.what = UPDATE_TAG;
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 200);
  }
})

...

final int UPDATE_TAG = 1;

public void updateView() {
  // Code where View.GONE and View.VISIBLE + invalidate is used.
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message input_msg) {
    if(msg.what == UPDATE_TAG) {
      updateView();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Enjoyable? No. But it does work! Thanks a lot, hope this answer will help other people as well.

Comment: I just needed the visibility change in the updated view. I did not have to do any invalidation.

Comment: I still think there has to be a better solution to this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this changes

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/control_scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:background="#99000000"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Quit the     `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: First thing I tried was wrap_content, however this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `LinearLayout` uses some kind of caching mechanism to avoid measuring childs every time. Or maybe I'm wrong.

However, you can try to use `RelativeLayout` instead of bunch of `LinearLayout`. This will solve your problem and also this will be much more efficient, since nested `ViewGroup`s isn't good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and set the ScrollView height to "wrap_content" so that even if the child views change the ScrollView can adjust to the new setting

Comment: First thing I tried, obviously. But this does not fix the problem.